# Counting trailing white spaces

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I need help creating a sed script that counts trailing white spaces with the `sed` command.

I can count the the words in a line by using `sed -n '$='` but how would I do that for spaces and trailing spaces?

New to `bash` so I appreciate any help I can get,
Thanks

****Edit***:*

I have to use `sed` for this so what If I just want to just print the lines (with trailing white spaces) instead of counting them?

Can I use `p` and do this:

```
sed  '/  /p' space.sed
```

Not sure how to signify two consecutive blank spaces, I would have a file with no leading spaces so this would detect the trailing spaces.

Comment: That `sed` command doesn't count words of a line.

Comment: It's possible, but don't. Sed only manipulates strings, it has no notion of numbers or counting.

Comment: According to http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-48 sed -n '$=' counts the number of lines in a file

Comment: This is an `awk` job, why not use it? Does your system only have `sed`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sed -n '$='` is **not**

> counting the the words in a line

it prints the line number of the last line in your file. so it counts the lines in file.

This could count the trailing whitespaces in each line. (If you want a sum of them, it is really easy.)

```
 awk '{t=length($0);sub(" *$","");print t-length($0)}' file
```

e.g I have a file (named as `f`) with following content, (**the ending "dots" don't exist, just for showing the trailing spaces**).

```
aaaaa     .
bbbbb    .
ccccc   .
```

with the awk one-liner above:

```
kent$  awk '{t=length($0);sub(" *$","");print t-length($0)}' f
5
4
3
```

**EDIT**

since `sed` is a must for solving this problem ( I cannot understand why though, unless it was a homework). This line works for your need, note that, **GNU Sed** is required:

```
kent$   sed -r 's/(.*\S)( *$)/expr length "\2"/ge'  f                                                                                                                        
5
4
3
```

- in above sed line, only `sed` was used `expr` cannot be counted as a tool right? so can it be called a "sed alone" solution?
- anyway, you are trying to screw a screw with a hammer.

I just saw the update in your question, if you just want to print the lines with trailing spaces, it is alot easier: (IMO, grep would be the best tool for this)

```
 sed -n '/ \+$/p' file
```

will do.

Comment: thanks for the help, your solution works great. I need to do it with sed though. Could you elaborate on how to count spaces or trailing/leading spaces with sed and explain a solution with sed?

Comment: @Charly why 'sed'? anyway, are you allowed to do it with sed and other tools? like `bc`, `wc` or even with small bash script? or you can only do with a sed one-liner?

Comment: I'm allowed to use tools with sed like the ones you mentioned, it would be great if you can explain a way with wc/bc. I just wanted to see a way it could be done with sed alone to better understand because I'm new to this language

Comment: this is apart of a homework which is to show lines that just contain trailing spaces, I re-noted that in edit (2). Sorry for making it more complicated than it should've been.

Comment: @Charly I added a sed solution for your edit(2). check the end part of my answer.